# Graph Copy file operation giving access denied error for app registration

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I make a copy item request to the Graph API (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy), I get an "Access Denied" error on the request. My app registration already requests Files.ReadWrite.All and Sites.ReadWrite.All with admin consent. Shouldn't that scope grant access to copy operations for all files?

Request and Response below:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{sourceDriveId}/items/{sourceItemId}/copy HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0......
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 211
Expect: 100-continue

{"name" : "Copy-01U5HU23DLMANTOZOCBRCKZAXZ22PYNRGR.pptx", "parentReference" :  { "driveId": "{targetDriveId}",  "id": "{targetFolderId}" } } }

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 7c26c462-805f-4c26-90e3-8ee22ba719c6
client-request-id: 7c26c462-805f-4c26-90e3-8ee22ba719c6
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Canada East","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_10"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Length: 279

{
  "error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "Access denied",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-07-20T02:45:37",
      "request-id": "7c26c462-805f-4c26-90e3-8ee22ba719c6",
      "client-request-id": "7c26c462-805f-4c26-90e3-8ee22ba719c6"
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to create folders using the same api permissions in the app registration. I am generating token using Client credentials flow.

Comment: As you are using client credential flow, it may not understand `me` . So use this API call with userid. `/users/{userId}/drive/items/{itemId}/copy`

Comment: I tried with this API too- /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/copy but got the same error. Am I missing any configuration here with the app reg? This call is successful when authenticated with a service account.

Comment: I have updated the final request I tried with.

Comment: Please check the token in https://jwt.ms and see if the permissions are there or not.

Comment: The delegated permissions dont show up in the token when checked in jwt.io. That explains the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use application permissions for client credential flow.

Comment: Hi @Shalankara Roy, If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Please add the Application permissions for the client credential flow. You should also not use `me` as we are not authenticating with user. You can use `users/userid` to access a specific user related data in the API call for client credential flow.